# Dropdown works only once in WordPress on bootstrap 4

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, dropdown

on my site: http://dogadajsie.eu you can click on "Przedimki" dropdown button and it will work, however only once. Once you click somewhere else and the dropdown rolls back, it won't dropdown once you click on "Przedimki" again.

I have read all the articles and other questions on stack overflow that suggested that maybe I should move the bootstrap.js import into header (as it currently is in footer) however it didn't work

all the rest of the examples were usually based on particular scenarios which don't apply in my case hence my question to you guys

to see the code that actually may help here please head over to http://dogadajsie.eu and look for "Przedimki" dropdown in sidebar.

No error messages really. I checked it with chrome's "inspect" and the behavior is that first click adds class "open" to: li#menu-item-222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bootstrap dropdown you need `popperJs` installed on your machine, so add this `CDN` in your code !!

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Happy coding !!